# Uneven column height in JTable/NETBEANS GUI Builder

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I'm trying to create a JTable based on a spec, where column heights are not necessarily even across a row.  For example, something like this:

[image]

Our spacing will follow a regular patthern.  For example, column A height will be normal (height = defualt row height), column B height will be 3 rows per entry, column C will be 2 rows per entry and so forth....  Once set, the pattern won't need altered, and we will not need to add new rows dynamically.  That is, our entire dataset is available at table construction.

I'm having trouble finding how to define such a pattern in JTable.  I'm using NETBeans GUI builder, if that offers any new functionality.  Is JTable capable of such formatting?

Comment: There use to be a really good set of examples, but they are longer available :( - However, you can sometimes find individual examples, like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiSpanCellTableExample.htm) or maybe [this](https://ytoh.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/creating-a-span-table-in-swing/)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Gee, that's a lotta code :)

Comment: Yeah, you're asking for something that was never designed ;)